# Trying to create Tables using SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new to android. I'm trying to create table, add a record and checking the record the code is given below. The problem is the table named TABLE_LOGIN is created as well as the checking is working fine on the table, but the second table TABLE_REG is not created as given in the Logcat.

**Database Helper:**

```
package com.intraharyana.tamber.intraharyana;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public static final String DATABASE_NAME="NIC.db";
public static final String TABLE_LOGIN ="employee_login";
public static final String LOGIN_COL_1 ="USER_ID";
public static final String LOGIN_COL_2 ="PASSWORD";
public static final String TABLE_REG="employee_info";
public static final String REG_COL_1="SALARY_ACC";
public static final String REG_COL_2="DOB";
public static final String REG_COL_3="DOJ";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(LOGIN_COL_1, "admin");
    contentValues.put(LOGIN_COL_2, "admin");
    db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, contentValues);
    ContentValues contentValues1= new ContentValues();
    contentValues1.put(REG_COL_1, "1234567890");
    contentValues1.put(REG_COL_2, "28/01/1994");
    contentValues1.put(REG_COL_3, "01/01/2016");
    db.insert(TABLE_REG, null, contentValues1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_LOGIN + "(USER_ID VARCHAR PRIMARY     KEY,PASSWORD TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_REG + "(SALARY_ACC VARCHAR PRIMARY                KEY,DOB VARCHAR, DOJ VARCHAR)");
 }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists "+ TABLE_LOGIN);
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists "+ TABLE_REG);
    onCreate(db);

}
public Cursor checkLogin(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from "+ TABLE_LOGIN,null);
    return cursor;

}
public Cursor checknewReg(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor1= db.rawQuery("select * from "+ TABLE_REG,null);
    return cursor1;
}

}`
```

**NewRegister Class**

```
package com.intraharyana.tamber.intraharyana;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

  public class NewRegister extends Activity {
DatabaseHelper mydb;
EditText emp_DOB,emp_DOJ,salaryacc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.newregister);
emp_DOB=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.emp_DOB);
    emp_DOJ=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.emp_DOJ);
    salaryacc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.salaryacc);

    mydb=new DatabaseHelper(this);


}
 @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public  void checkReg(View view) {

    String salary=salaryacc.getText().toString();
    NewRegister ng= new NewRegister();

    Cursor c = mydb.checknewReg();
    int x=0;
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if (c.getString(0).equals(salaryacc.getText().toString().toLowerCase())
                    && c.getString(1).equals(emp_DOB.getText().toString())
                    && c.getString(2).equals(emp_DOJ.getText().toString())) {

                Intent i = new Intent(this, NewRegister2.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                x=1;
            }

        }
        while (c.moveToNext());
        if(x==0)
            Toast.makeText(this,"Incorrect Credentials...Please Check again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
03-29 23:48:19.037 21421-21421/com.intraharyana.tamber.intraharyana E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.intraharyana.tamber.intraharyana, PID: 21421
                                                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                                          at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4240)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184)
                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20910)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                          at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4235)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184) 
                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20910) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183) 
                                                                                       Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: employee_info (code 1): , while compiling: select * from employee_info
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1440)
                                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1379)
                                                                                          at com.intraharyana.tamber.intraharyana.DatabaseHelper.checknewReg(DatabaseHelper.java:54)
                                                                                          at com.intraharyana.tamber.intraharyana.NewRegister.checkReg(NewRegister.java:151)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                          at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4235) 
                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184) 
                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20910) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

Comment: Thanks uninstalling and reinstalling worked @BobMalooga

Comment: need a suggestion @BobMalooga . I want to connect my app to webservices any link you can share from where I can know the basic functionality?

Comment: Google, google and google again. I think there's half a billion results...

Comment: @BobMalooga I tried it. Those half a billion took me on half a billion paths. I want to know a specific method that you would recommend being so familiar with android

Comment: I'm not familiar with webservices, though. I only once wrote the server side webServices for an iOS app (which I didn't write - It was a collaboration between a VB.NET and a iOS dev teams). I guess words like JSON, REST and such should be the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Wild Guess**: You probably added the second table after a previous run.
Uninstall your app and re-run it